# Unable to run Studio-3T 2018.1.0 In Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Tags: command-line, mate, mongodb

I am new to the Linux environment, and now I am facing some problems while running MongoDB GUI Studio 3T.

[image]

I have installed 'Studio-3T 2018.1.0' in Ubuntu Mate 16.04

1. First I extracted the tar file and then I changed the permission.

   ```
   chmod +x studio-3t-linux-x86-no-shell.sh
   ```
2. Then I ran the file `./studio-3t-linux-x86-no-shell.sh`
3. Finally it started executing and installed in my machine.
4. But at last when I am trying to open/run the application it threw a startup error.

   ```
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display
   at t3.dataman.mongodb.app.Studio3TApp.mq(Studio3TApp.java:49)
   at t3.dataman.mongodb.app.Studio3TApp.main(Studio3TApp.java:39)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
   at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:81)
   at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(UnixLauncher.java:62)
   ```

Comment: Generally it is better to include the text of the error messages than to paste a picture of the error.

Answer (score 1):

On my 64-bit system I can install and launch it with:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://download.studio3t.com/studio-3t/linux/2020.1.2/studio-3t-linux-x64.tar.gz
tar -xzf studio-3t-linux-x64.tar.gz
sh studio-3t-linux-x64-no-shell.sh
# then it starts when installer is finished
```

If you have 64-bit system you can try this way.

On 32-bit I get the same error as you wrote. I recommend to contact Studio-3T directly.

Comment: I have 32 bit machine

Comment: Facing same **error**

Comment: On 32-bit I get same error.

Comment: Seems: 404 Not Found! Try it: https://download.studio3t.com/studio-3t/linux/2020.1.2/studio-3t-linux-x64.tar.gz

Comment: @MaxBase Do you know what is the year today? The answer was originally written i 2018. Thanks anyway, edited.

Comment: Yeah my friend, No problem. I mention this because it's on first page of google. Anyway, thanks you.